# Running CMD on a restricted system(Windows 7 school computer)

Tags: windows, java, cmd.exe, notepad

On my school computer I am trying to run cmd so I can test my java code for my engineering class. I do not want to use an IED. I am trying to use a bat file to open cmd but when i run the program I get a prompt that says "this program is blocked by group policy'. The window title reads 'E:\cmd.bat'. How can I get around this or open cmd another way. All answers and advice is appreciated

Comment: You could always create a shortcut to the file. i.e. `C:\Program Files (x86)\java\jre\bin\java.exe -jar jarfile` or type it into run. **This will only work with apps that have a UI.**

Comment: There used to be a workaround with the `calc.exe` from one of it's menu options or something to get around this restriction but I don't remember the specifics and I think MS patched it. You may need to ask the admin that sets the policy to allow you to do this is the classwork requires it otherwise talk with your professor regarding the issue. If you are allowed to modify registry settings and have local admin access, then you'd have to look into this restriction to see how to undo it if you can do so plus superseding any AD GP's that are applied with applicable effective precedence.

Comment: It's best to talk to your school IT person, prevents you from getting in trouble if something goes sideways

Comment: Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [On-Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your IT department.

Comment: If you need this for a class, you should talk to the teacher of that class about getting the access you need.

Comment: "I do not want to use an IED": so just give you an answer and you won't blow anything up?

Answer (score 0):

If you have USB or any portable media access,  you can install  [Cygwin lite](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cygwin-lite/). This will give you a bash shell on the computer.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you writing a batch file to open a cmd prompt to run a java application?

Try:

Start menu -> Run -> java -jar %JAR_PATH%